# Notation in Financial Math

Tags: notation, finance

I am very close to showing part b of this question and think that the reason my solution doesn't match up is because I don't understand a piece of notation.The notation I don't understand is $\textbf{$e^T$}$ on the bottom line inside the function $h$.

I am at the point:

$$E[f(W)] = \frac{1}{a}\huge{[}\normalsize 1 - \exp\{-aw\xi_0 r_0 + aw\big(\frac{1}{2}aw\xi V\xi^T - \xi r^T\big)\}\huge{]} $$

[image]

Comment: That $\boldsymbol{e}$ in $\boldsymbol{e}^T$ is both boldfaced and in italics, unlike the $e$ for exponentials, so I believe it is a vector (of what, I don't know.)